# Should I IUnknown::Release interfaces created with DllGetClassObject

Tags: c, windows, com

I'm trying to debug some code that uses COM, which I am a beginner at.
The two calls to IUnknown::Release at the end have got me worried.
The interfaces were created with DllGetClassObject and IClassFactory::CreateInstance.
I have seen other similar code that does not call IUnknown::Release on these - which is correct?

```
int OpenMixer_Win_DirectSound(px_mixer *Px, int index)
{
   DSPROPERTY_DIRECTSOUNDDEVICE_DESCRIPTION_DATA desc;
   HMODULE hDsound = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
   GCO DllGetClassObject;
   IClassFactory *pcf = NULL;
   IKsPropertySet *pps = NULL;
   HRESULT hr;
   ULONG bytes;
   LPGUID guidIn;
   LPGUID guidOut;
   UINT deviceIn = -1;
   UINT deviceOut = -1;
   int ret = FALSE;

   guidIn = PaWinDS_GetStreamInputGUID(Px->pa_stream);
   guidOut = PaWinDS_GetStreamOutputGUID(Px->pa_stream);

   do {
      hDsound = LoadLibraryA("dsound.dll");
      if (hDsound == NULL) {
         break;
      }

      DllGetClassObject = (GCO) GetProcAddress(hDsound, "DllGetClassObject");
      if (DllGetClassObject == NULL) {
         break;
      }
      hr = DllGetClassObject(&CLSID_DirectSoundPrivate,
                             &IID_IClassFactory,
                             (void **)(&pcf));
      if (hr || pcf == NULL) {
         break;
      }

      hr = IClassFactory_CreateInstance(pcf,
                                        NULL,
                                        &IID_IKsPropertySet,
                                        (void **)(&pps));
      if (hr || pps == NULL) {
         break;
      }

      /* Do stuff with the interfaces */

   } while( FALSE );

   if (pps) {
      IUnknown_Release(pps);
   }

   if (pcf) {
      IUnknown_Release(pcf);
   }

   // Free the library.  Note that portaudio also opens dsound.dll
   // so this probably doesn't do anything until Pa_Terminate is called.
   if (hDsound != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
      FreeLibrary(hDsound);
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is C? Not C++ or C#? ??

Comment: This is why you want to use a wrapper that does the reference counting for you.

Comment: what makes you think it isn't C?

Comment: I thought maybe you had your languages wrong because of your reference (in the text) to identifiers with `::`; but as the code didn't use them, I didn't edit the tags.

Comment: Ah, no it's C.  I just used '::' because that's what the ms documentation uses since these interfaces are not bound to any specific language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.  Both functions create a new interface pointer, they will have a reference count of 1, the AddRef() function was already called.  When you're done with it then you *have* to call Release().  You'll leak memory if you don't.  *Every* interface in COM works this way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As seen in [DllGetClassObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sample, the return ppvObj will have a refcount.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `DllGetClassObject()` will create an object and ***pass ownership*** of that object to your code. Your code will now ***own*** the object and be responsible for releasing it by calling `IUnknown::Release()`.